NVIDIA drivers installation "sudo ubuntu-drivers list" gives no output in terminal
Edit: as suggested by this kind user, I've unscrewed the command by entering the following code:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update

Which now allows me to select the Nvidia driver in the "Additional Drivers" window. However, when I try to apply this change of drivers I am met with this error prompt that I am going to create a new question for.

I freshly installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on an old Laptop - ASUSTeK Computer Inc. K53SD and realized that the system is using my Intel Graphics instead of an existing GeForce 610M.
I am trying to follow the NVIDIA drivers installation guide but fail to proceed due to an unknown reason: the sudo ubuntu-drivers list command doesn't output anything : the blinker on the terminal just stops for a moment and then the terminal is just expecting another command without giving me any options or output. I am probably really stupid for not seeing the problem myself but I am at a complete loss of ideas.
I am by no means a competent or an experienced user, I only came down to using the command line because despite
the proprietary drivers being selected in "Software & Updates" the "Additional Drivers" window is completely empty
sudo lspci -v outputs the following :
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
Memory at dc400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at e000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 610M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GeForce GT 610M
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
Memory at db000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at c8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at dc000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

According to the journal it appears to be an issue with nouveau driver :
17:17:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
17:17:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
17:17:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
17:17:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084d failed with error -2
17:17:06 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084 failed with error -2
16:51:02 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
16:51:02 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
16:51:02 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084d failed with error -2
16:51:02 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084 failed with error -2
16:50:54 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: [DRM/00000000:kmsOutp] [LOAD_DETECT data:00000154] load:07 (ret:7)
16:50:50 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: [DRM/00000000:kmsOutp] [LOAD_DETECT data:00000154] load:07 (ret:7)
16:49:46 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: [DRM/00000000:kmsOutp] [LOAD_DETECT data:00000154] load:07 (ret:7)
16:49:45 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
16:49:45 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
16:49:45 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084d failed with error -2
16:49:45 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084 failed with error -2
16:49:42 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: [DRM/00000000:kmsOutp] [LOAD_DETECT data:00000154] load:07 (ret:7)
16:39:37 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: [DRM/00000000:kmsOutp] [LOAD_DETECT data:00000154] load:07 (ret:7)
16:38:21 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: [DRM/00000000:kmsOutp] [LOAD_DETECT data:00000154] load:07 (ret:7)
16:38:18 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: init failed, -19
16:38:18 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: msvld: unable to load firmware data
16:38:18 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084d failed with error -2
16:38:18 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for nouveau/nvd9_fuc084 failed with error -2
16:38:16 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: [DRM/00000000:kmsOutp] [LOAD_DETECT data:00000154] load:07 (ret:7)
16:37:24 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: [DRM/00000000:kmsOutp] [LOAD_DETECT data:00000154] load:07 (ret:7)


note launchpad bugs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/2028165 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/2051436

Try this:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
ubuntu-drivers devices  # to check recommended driver versions

Here is the reference article.

Thanks! Well good news the command is now working as intended and suggested me the 390 Nvidia driver I am looking to install. The driver now also appears on the "Additional Drivers" window in "Software & Updates".
However, now I get a new kind of error. When I tried "sudo ubuntu-drivers install" I got a bunch of errors and even a "Ubuntu 24.04 internal error" prompt that asked me to report the error (which I did). The log in /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.157/build/make.log is opaque to me. When I tried selecting the Nvidia driver in "Software & Updates" I got "error exit status 10 (313)"
